# Reactjs: how to update vote counts in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code below was designed to update a voting system. It works fine by displaying the results as the page loads.

Here is my problem: I need to update each user's vote any time the **Get Vote Count** button is clicked.

In the backend, I have php code which returns the array data as per below.

Can someone help me with displaying the array values and updating eg (vote to 11) depending on how the user voted?

```
<?php
// Update user response on a post

    $return_arr[]= array("vote"=>"11");

    echo json_encode($return_arr);
    exit;

?>
```

Here is the array return by axios API Call

```
[{"vote":"11"}]
```

**Here is the code**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { id: "1", name: "Tony", vote: "3" },
        { id: "2", name: "Mark", vote: "6" },
        { id: "3", name: "Joy", vote: "2" }
      ]
    });
  }

  handleVote(person_id, person_vote) {
    const data_vote = {
      person_id: person_id,
      person_vote: person_vote
    };
    axios
      .get("http://localhost/vote.php", { data_vote })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ result_vote: response.data });
        console.log(this.state.result_vote);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map((person, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {person.name} --(vote count: {person.vote})
                <br />
                <input
                  type="button"
                  value="Get Vote Counts"
                  onClick={() => this.handleVote(person.id, person.vote)}
                />
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: console.log(this.state.result_vote) statement can be triggered with the previous state content and display your previous state. Always keep in mind that this.setState is an async function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your `data` state after getting the `vote` data from the fetch response. You have `person_id` in your handler and getting an array including `vote` value. So, `map` through your `data` state find the relevant `person` and update its `vote` value.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { id: "1", name: "Tony", vote: "3" },
        { id: "2", name: "Mark", vote: "6" },
        { id: "3", name: "Joy", vote: "2" }
      ]
    });
  }

  handleVote(person_id, person_vote) {
    const data_vote = {
      person_id: person_id,
      person_vote: person_vote
    };
    axios
      .get("http://localhost/vote.php", { data_vote })
      .then(response => {
        const newData = this.state.data.map(person => {
          if (person.id !== person_id) return person;
          return { ...person, vote: response.data[0].vote };
        });
        this.setState(state => ({
          data: newData
        }));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map(person => (
              <li key={person.id}>
                {person.name} --(vote count: {person.vote})
                <br />
                <input
                  type="button"
                  value="Get Vote Counts"
                  onClick={() => this.handleVote(person.id, person.vote)}
                />
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Try to avoid using an index as a key. You have a `person.id` so use it in your `map` method. Also, as an enhancement, you can refactor your code and create a `Person` component. You can pass the related data and vote handler then setup the update logic there.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { id: "1", name: "Tony", vote: "3" },
        { id: "2", name: "Mark", vote: "6" },
        { id: "3", name: "Joy", vote: "2" },
      ],
    });
  }

  handleVote = (person) => {
    const data_vote = {
      person_id: person.id,
      person_vote: person.vote,
    };
    axios
      .get("http://localhost/vote.php", { data_vote })
      .then((response) => {
        const newData = this.state.data.map((el) => {
          if (el.id !== person.id) return el;
          return { ...el, vote: response.data[0].vote };
        });
        this.setState({ data: newData });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map(person => (
              <Person
                key={person.id}
                person={person}
                handleVote={this.handleVote}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}

const Person = (props) => {
  const { person, handleVote } = props;
  const onVote = () => handleVote(person);
  return (
    <li>
      {person.name} --(vote count: {person.vote})
      <br />
      <input type="button" value="Get Vote Counts" onClick={onVote} />
    </li>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much sir

Answer (score 0):

So, since your handler function is getting the `person_id` and your call is returning the new vote count, you should update the current person object in your data table in state.

Here is an example:

[Updating the vote count for the current user](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3lryy65zy)

Comment: Thanks so much sir